# cad to shapefile conversion

Tags: arcgis-10.0, shapefile, arcobjects, cad

I use ArcGIS 10.1 & arcobjects.net.

I have the following code:

```
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.Geoprocessor gp = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.Geoprocessor();
        gp.OverwriteOutput = true;

        ESRI.ArcGIS.ConversionTools.FeatureClassToShapefile tool = new ESRI.ArcGIS.ConversionTools.FeatureClassToShapefile();


        tool.Input_Features = @"F:\test buffer of JAMNAGAR SHP FILES ex3\FOOTPATH.dwg";
        tool.Output_Folder = @"C:\Temp1";
        gp.Execute(tool, null);
```

but after executing this code I got an error

> "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM
>   component. "

If anyone have any suggestion or any sample for this conversion or any link then send me please

Comment: are you able to convert using arcpy? This would prove that the conversion is possible and the file isn't broken. Does the tool require an output name as well as output folder?

Comment: sorry i dont know arccpy?it require only output folder location where all files are stored.if you have sample using arccpy then send me link or having some solution regarding above then it will useful for me.

Comment: If not arcpy then toolbox. Search for the geoprocessing tool Feature Class to Shapefile and try to convert manually, this will also give you a good idea of what parameters the object expects to be set, if this fails then the dwg file is broken and no code fixing is going to help.

Comment: @michael Sir:i did it manually and it work fine but y my code giving this error i don't figure it out yet any have idea regarding this...

Comment: Is this a standalone application or an add-in? Standalone applications need an AOInitialize to grab the license.

Comment: standalone application

Comment: look up http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004200000006000000 you need to 'grab' an ESRI license before you do anything important; some objects will work without a license but you can't do anything meaningful until your application is appropriately licensed.

Answer (score 2):

If .dwg files are simalar to .dxf files then part of your problem may be with the parameter you are providing for `Input_Features`, i.e. the path to your .dwg file.

I perform the same geoprocessing operation `ESRI.ArcGIS.ConversionTools.FeatureClassToShapefile` on .dxf files. Because the .dxf file contains subsets of data within it (i.e. an annotation layer, geometry layers, etc.) you will need to add the sub dataset name to your path. In my case I have .dxf files that have the following sub datasets:

- Annotation
- Multipath
- Point
- Polygon
- Polyline

Although these are contained in the same .dxf file they are essentially different datasets so to export the Point data I would need append Point to the `Input_Features` parameter to run `ESRI.ArcGIS.ConversionTools.FeatureClassToShapefile` like this:

```
//create geoprocessor object, FeatureClassToShapefile object, and set input parameters
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.Geoprocessor GP = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.Geoprocessor();
ESRI.ArcGIS.ConversionTools.FeatureClassToShapefile FCToShapeFile = new ESRI.ArcGIS.ConversionTools.FeatureClassToShapefile();
FCToShapeFile.Input_Features = "C:\CAD_to_Shp\temp.dxf\Point"; //appended Point to the path to input features
FCToShapeFile.Output_Folder = "C:\CAD_to_Shp\";

//run geoprocessor operation
GP.Execute(FCToShapeFile, null);
```

**Because this is a standalone application make sure you have taken the steps that @MichaelMiles-Stimson has suggested to initialize the ESRI license.